# @ character is not working on cURL

Tags: php, curl, sms

I have tried to use `urlencode()` / `rawurlencode()` to convert the `@` symbol to `%40`, however in the SMS `%40` is shown as the entity, e.g. `kamalkamal002%40gmail.com`.

My code is as follows:

```
$message = "Percentage:99%"."\r\n";
$message .="Email:kamalkamal002@gmail.com"."\r\n"; 

$numbers = implode(',', $numbers);

// Prepare data for POST request
$data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'username'=>"kamal002", 'numbers' => $numbers, "sendername" => $sender, "message" => $message, 'smstype'=>"PROMO");

// Send the POST request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://sms.bulksmsind.in/sendSMS?');
```

Comment: That's only partial code...

Comment: Could it be you dont need to urlencode it? By default you are already sending urlencoded form which the receiving server handle as such.

Comment: remaining code is only for cURL operation.

Comment: without using urlencode (); @ symbol is converted to something unknown like i in SMS.

Comment: try to replace @ with 0x00 character, also I doubt they expect gsm7 alphabet